# For loop only giving last value of the count as output

Tags: javascript

I have the below script:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fruits = array('banana','apple','orange');
for (var i = 0;i < fruits.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = fruits;
}
</script> 
<table id="table">
   <tr id="tr1">
      <td id="td1"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="tr2">
      <td id="td2"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

after executing the above i am only getting the output orange.
I want to get output 'banana','apple','orange' using above loop.

Comment: please format your question correctly

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fruits = ['banana','apple','orange'];
    document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = fruits.join();
</script>
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this would replace the for loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the bug:

```
document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = fruits;
                                         ^
                                         |
                                         |
                             you're overwriting previous text here
```

You probably mean `+=` instead.

Answer (score 0):

sorry boss its not array  ->  Array, try this and post the output

```
        var fru='';
        var fruits = Array('banana','apple','orange');
        for (var i = 0;i < fruits.length; i++) {
          fru+=" "+fruits[i]+",";}
        document.getElementById('td1').innerHTML=fru;
```

Comment: no way did you add fru+='...........'; like this, because + is used to concatinate, i posted it after testing it